Global function in external JS file not accesible in magento
I develop a chat widget application that allows customers to add our small widget script in their website and inturn allows website visitors to chat with customer support executives(similar to freshhhchaat).
The script I give customers is like
<script>
let myScript = document.createElement('script')
myScript.setAttribute('src', 'https:/mydomain.com/js/widget.js')
myScript.setAttribute('type', "module");
document.body.appendChild(myScript)
myScript.onload = () => {
 myScriptInit({ // function in widget.js
   customer: "2121afasd23123"
 });
}
</script>  

This works on all sites except those on magento.
On magento I get error
myScriptInit is not defined

I was reading regarding this and it seems something to do with require.js. How can I modify the widget.js script to that global functions declared in those are available?
